# Avoid being recognized as spam

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I'm trying to send succesfully emails from python using smtp google and smtplib. The email is sent right, but the receiver gets the email as spam.

Is there something about the headers or how can I avoid to be recognized as spam?

```
from flask import render_template, current_app
from flask_babel import _
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.headerregistry import Address
from email.utils import make_msgid

def send_email(subject, receiver, plain_text, html_text):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Message-ID'] = make_msgid()
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = Address(name, username, 'gmail.com')
    msg['To'] = Address(receiver.fullname(), receiver.email.split('@')[0], receiver.email.split('@')[1])
    msg.set_content(plain_text)
    msg.add_alternative(html_text, subtype='html')
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()
```

Comment: Are the messages likely to trigger a bayesian spam filter? If there was some easy `msg['PinkySwearImNotSpam'] = True` then every spammer would set that, and it would be ignored anyway.

Comment: Hello {{ name }},

To verify your account {{ click here }}.

Alternatively, you can paste the following link in your browser's address bar:

{{ Link }}

Comment: My message looks like the above one, simple verification email. The link has a token so maybe the ratio text/link is won by the link and that triggers spam... I don't know what else could it be.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you set up both **SPF** and **DKIM** on your domain to add weight to your outgoing emails. Read more about setting up SPF and DKIM [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en). It will require some DNS alterations which are easy enough.

Also, a small message in a bit of HTML may be construed as spam to many spam filters. Consider sending either a plan text email or an HTML email with a plain text variant.